# Setting background of content control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

```
<UserControl .....>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AViewModel}">
    <vw:AView />
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BViewModel}">
    <vw:BView />
  </DataTemplate>

  <ContentControl x:Name="chartScreen" Content="{Binding Screen}" Background="Yellow" />
</UserControl>
```

As you can see from above code, ContentControl is setting its content through binding to ViewModel's Screen property. Screen property will return an instance of AViewModel or BViewModel, depending on some condition. The problem is, when UserControl is loaded on screen, Screen property is null, so there is no content set yet. At this point, I would like to set some background for the ContentControl, but I cannot find a way how to do this? Background="Yellow" does nothing...

Any ideas how to set the background of ContentControl? This backgound should be applied always, even when content is displaying AView or Biew, or null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just wrap your `ContentControl` in a `Border`

```
<Border Background="Yellow">
  <ContentControl x:Name="chartScreen"
                  Content="{Binding Screen}" />
</Border>
```

If all you have in your `UserControl` is your `ContentControl`, just set the `Background` on the `UserControl` itself. That would remove the extra `Border` as well.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this :

```
 <ContentControl x:Name="chartScreen" Content="{Binding Screen}" Background="Yellow">
       <ContentControl.Triggers>    
           <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
               <Trigger.Value>
                   <Border Background="Yellow"/>
               </Trigger.Value> 
           </Trigger>  
       </ContentControl.Triggers>    
 </ContentControl>
```

Comment: I will mark you answer as helpful, although it doesn't quite answer the question. If you read the last part sentence, background should be applied always, not just when Content is null.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this in WPF:

```
 <ContentControl>
      <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content}" Value="{x:Null}">
              <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" />
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```